# Superposition of elementary Dirac measures: looking for reference or explanation

Tags: integration, measure-theory, reference-request, dirac-delta, bochner-spaces

Reading a paper concerning transport of measures, I came accross the following sentence:

"...the fundamental fact that a generic measure $\mu$ can be written as the superposition of elementary Dirac masses, that is:
$$  \mu = \int_{\text{supp }\mu} \delta_x \, d\mu (x), $$
where $\text{supp }\mu$ belongs to an appropriate $\sigma$-algebra and the representation has to be understood in the sense of Bochner integrals.
"

I conviced myself that this is reasonably true working with toy examples involving step functions (i.e, a finite number of Dirac measures in principle), but I cannot find a reference for the general case which - at least according to the authors - should be a well-known fact; neither I can find a proof on my own since the definition of Bochner integral is quite abstract. Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Comment: physic stack exchange maybe ?

Comment: Do you actually believe? I mean this sound raw and technical measure theory to me..

Comment: Maybe you can find this result in "Vector Measures" by Diestel & Uhl. I don't have it by my side at the moment, but it has a lot of similar results related to Bochner integrals.

Comment: I will have a look, thank you very much!